# What are the default point shapes for leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

What are the default point shapes when styling geojson points layer?  I am would like to use some other shapes, pentagons, octagons, stars, etc., in my web map but I cant seam to find where they are listed in the the leaflet documentation.  I am using Qgis and Qgis2Web to create my javascript.

```
function style_Inlets_8_0() {
            return {
                pane: 'pane_Inlets_8',
                shape: 'square',
                radius: 4.0,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'rgba(50,87,128,1.0)',
                dashArray: '',
                lineCap: 'butt',
                lineJoin: 'miter',
                weight: 2.0,
                fill: true,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                fillColor: 'rgba(72,123,182,1.0)',
                interactive: true,
            }
        }
        map.createPane('pane_Inlets_8');
        map.getPane('pane_Inlets_8').style.zIndex = 408;
        map.getPane('pane_Inlets_8').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'normal';
        var layer_Inlets_8 = new L.geoJson(json_Inlets_8, {
            attribution: '',
            interactive: true,
            dataVar: 'json_Inlets_8',
            layerName: 'layer_Inlets_8',
            pane: 'pane_Inlets_8',
            onEachFeature: pop_Inlets_8,
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                var context = {
                    feature: feature,
                    variables: {}
                };
                return L.shapeMarker(latlng, style_Inlets_8_0(feature));
            },
        });
        bounds_group.addLayer(layer_Inlets_8);
        map.addLayer(layer_Inlets_8);
```

Comment: If you have `L.shapMarker` in your code, then you're using https://github.com/rowanwins/Leaflet.SvgShapeMarkers , and the documentation about available shapes is there.